# right side alt shift in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, append

How does one append all lines in a SQL query with text?

In order to add something to the front of my lines of code I can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> down the left side and type something to change

```
example-1
example-12
example-123
example-1234
example-12345
```

to

```
a.example-1
a.example-12
a.example-123
a.example-1234
a.example-12345
```

but if I want to add something to the right side, it turns out like this

```
a.example-1*
a.example-1*
a.example-1*3
a.example-1*34
a.example-1*345
```

when i want it to look like this

```
a.example-1*
a.example-12*
a.example-123*
a.example-1234*
a.example-12345*
```

So, how do I do this?  Is it possible to append all lines with something with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> or is there another method?

*Edit example

To clarify, I need to edit the text in my SQL code, not the text within my tables and such.  Ex.:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
   [day]
  ,[workout_name]
  ,[reps]
FROM [tom].[dbo].[workout_routine]
```

but instead of having the commas at the beginning of [day], [workout_name], let's say I need them at the end, like:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
   [day],
   [workout_name],
   [reps]
FROM [tom].[dbo].[workout_routine]
```

Because <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> works and aligns at any column of text, but I need to know if there is a way to be able to add something to the end of lines of *differing lengths*.

Comment: Something like [this](http://zippy.gfycat.com/WellmadeDefiantAfricanmolesnake.gif), but with lines of different lengths

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function in mysql.

```
Select concat(row, ' text after row') from table
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to modify a script, you can use Regex to replace $ which represents the end of line character. So if you were in Notepad++, you can do a find and replace for $. Make sure you allow Regular expression in the search mode.